# How do I fix this syntax problem? I am confused

Tags: python

I don't know what I am doing wrong here

```
p = ["5","3","4","5"]
for i in range(len(p),-1,-1):
    print(p[i])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jeffbezoz\Desktop\vbvbvbvbvbvbvvmvm.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(p[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `range(len(p) - 1,-1,-1):`

Answer (score 1):

That's an `IndexError`, not a `SyntaxError`, it's because you're starting the loop at `len(p)`, when it should be `len(p) - 1`:

```
for i in range(len(p) - 1, -1, -1):
```

A better way to loop through a list backwards is using `reversed`:

```
for x in reversed(p):
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
5
4
3
5
```